# How to query a Sybase database from the shell?

Tags: shell, unix, sybase

I want to write a shell script wherein I have to find out the name of the
tables begining with ad (I have written a query for that) and then I have to
take backup of each such table present in database. I am using sybase database.
How can I process each and every table? Which variables do I need to take to
store the result of the above query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at dbschema.pl

http://www.peppler.org/downloads/dbschema-2_4_2.zip

I've used this script in production with success many times.

Comment: can you please highlight the sample snippet as i am new to both linux and sybase? I would really appreciate your help.. Thanx

Comment: Something like (can't check myself)
 perl [folder path]dbschema.pl –S[server] –U[user] –P[password] –D[database] -O2

This script will create ddl bcp-out scripts for database objects.